# ui-grid second col can edit or not judge by first col 's value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, ui-grid

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CtHG.png)

1.The request is weather the 'tax_amount' column need to be filled in or not decide by the first column: 'tax_type', 
ex:  tax_type = 1, tax_amount can edit,
     tax_type = 2, tax_amount can't edit.

can ui-grid do this requirement ?

Comment: How can I import a picture to stackoverflow ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cellEditableCondition: function ($scope) {
                                if ($scope.row.entity.bill_type_id === 'aaa') {
                                    return true
                                } else {
                                    return false
                                }
                            },

it's solve!